# Why pagination doesn't work on serverside proccessing of jquery datatables even though "recordsTotal" and "recordsFiltered" are equal

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

My datatable (jquery datatables 1.10.5) having server-side processing true. Everything works here except from pagination.  Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e9btzpox/5/
 . I have searched so many post ,Everywhere it says "recordsTotal" and "recordsFiltered" should be equal but this also doesn't work.

Here is sample of my code :

```
$table.dataTable({
    "serverSide": true,
        "processing": true,
        "processing": true,
        "columns": [
        ["data", 1],
        ["data", 2]
    ],
        "ajax": {
        "url": "/test/0",
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
            var data = json.aaData;
            return data;
        }
    },
        "createdRow": function (row, data, index) {
        var chk_name = 'chk_' + data[0].id;
        $('td:eq(0)', row)
            .html('<input name="' + chk_name + '" type="checkbox" value="1">');

        var select_name = 'select_' + data[0].id;
        html =
            '<select name="' + select_name + '">' + '<option value="">Select one</option>' + '<option>' + data[2].operation[0] + '</option>' + '<option>' + data[2].operation[1] + '</option>'; + '</select>';

        $('td:eq(1)', row).html(html);
    },
});
```

Here is sample of json response :-

```
{"draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": "11",
    "recordsFiltered": "11",

    "aaData": [
    [{
        "id": 1
    }, {
        "chk": "on"
    }, {
        "operation": ["Modify", "Delete"]
    }] 
  }
```

Updating with server side code :-

```
public class DataTableObject {
    int     draw;
    String  recordsTotal;
    String  recordsFiltered;
    List<Student> data;

    public int getDraw() {
        return draw;
    }
    public void setDraw(int draw) {
        this.draw = draw;
    }
    public String getRecordsTotal() {
        return recordsTotal;
    }
    public void setRecordsTotal(String recordsTotal) {
        this.recordsTotal = recordsTotal;
    }
    public String getRecordsFiltered() {
        return recordsFiltered;
    }
    public void setRecordsFiltered(String recordsFiltered) {
        this.recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered;
    }
    public List<Student> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(List<Student> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public List<Student> getAaData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setAaData(List<Student> aaData) {
        this.data = aaData;
    }
}
```

and json response is being prepare as :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            response.setContentType("application/json");
           List<Students> listOfStudent=           getStudentList();
          DataTableObject dataTableObject = new DataTableObject();
 dataTableObject.setDraw((Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("draw"))));
        dataTableObject.setRecordsTotal("2000");
        dataTableObject.setRecordsFiltered("2000");
        dataTableObject.setAaData(listOfStudent);
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
        String json = gson.toJson(dataTableObject);
        out.print(json);
}

public List<Students> getListOfStudents(){
List<Students> listOfStudent = new ArrayList<Students>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 200; i++) {
            aStudent = new Student();
            String [] names= new String [3];
            names[0]  = "Sandeep"+i;
            names[1] = "Jaspal"+i;
            names[2] = "Harpal"+i;
            aStudent.setId(""+i);
            aStudent.setChk("off");
            aStudent.setOperation(new String[]{"modify","delete"});
            listOfStudent.add(aStudent);
}
return listOfStudents;      
}
```

Comment: The pagination isn't working because you need to page the data in your server-side code.  The parameters `iDisplayLength` and `iDisplayStart` are passed to to `/test/0` and you need to use them in your query, otherwise ALL the data will be returned. You haven't added any server-side code so this is just a guess...

Comment: @markpsmith :thanks for helping me out here, i will update post with server side code  please have a look. I am kinda stuck here.

Comment: You need to incorporate the paging parameters into your query, although it looks like you're not actually using a database, but the principle should be the same.  Put a breakpoint in the server-side code & inspect `Request["iDisplayLength"]` and `Request["iDisplayStart"]`.

Comment: @markpsmith :I have these parameters in my request :- "draw","start","length",  search[value], search[regex], draw, columns[0][data], columns[0][name], columns[0][searchable], columns[0][orderable], columns[0][search][value], columns[0][search][regex], columns[1][data], columns[1][name], columns[1][searchable],, columns[1][orderable], columns[1][search][value],,columns[1][search][regex], order[0][column],,order[0][dir], but question is how to use these parameter at server side for pagination to work ??

Comment: The parameters you need are probably `start` and `length`.  I'm not very familiar with v1.10 so you may have to look at the documentation to confirm. Can you see the value of `start` change as you page through the results?

Answer (score 1):

With 1.10, the server gets parameters called `start` & `length` for the paging. You need to use these to page your list of students using `Skip()` and `Take()`.

e.g.

```
var start = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("start"));
var length = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("length"));
List<Students> listOfStudent = getStudentList();
List<Students> filteredList = listOfStudent.Skip(start).Take(length)
dataTableObject.setAaData(filteredList);
```

That also means your number of records (all and filtered) should be the count of items in those lists:

e.g. something like:

```
dataTableObject.setRecordsTotal(listOfStudent.Count());
dataTableObject.setRecordsFiltered(filteredList.Count());
```

**Note:** You have not shown any support for search and sort, but they need to occur before the pagination.

Answer (score 1):

I see some problem in pagination section when I send recordsTotal and recordsFilteres values as string, instead of integer. So your values should look like below, without quotes around :

```
"recordsTotal": 11,
"recordsFiltered": 11,
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain this assuming we are using jquery datatable server side paging with start = 0, length = 25

**recordsFiltered:** (Here age is dynamic parameter for filtering)

```
select * from students where IsDeleted = 0 AND age = 18 limit start, length
```

or it can be

```
select * from students where IsDeleted = 0 limit start, length
```

**recordsTotal:** (This is wrong if you are using)

```
select count(1) as Total from students where IsDeleted = 0 limit start, length
```

**recordsTotal:** (This is correct way for total use same query as recordsFiltered but omit limit clause)

```
select count(1) as Total from students where IsDeleted = 0 AND age = 18
```

or it can be

```
select count(1) as Total from students where IsDeleted = 0 limit start, length
```